# How to calculate the values and ratings of wound Induction Motor Rotor Resistance Starter resistors?

Tags: motor, dc-motor, brushless-dc-motor, generator, induction-motor

How to calculate the values and ratings for the Rotor Resistance Starter resistors?

Motor specs:

- 3 Phase 400V
- 1/2Hp
- 4 Pole
- 1750rpm
- Y connection

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To determine the rotor resistance values and related ratings for a rotor resistance starter, it is essential to establish the suitable starting torque and current appropriate for the motor. These requisites hinge on the motor's specifications and the nature of the load it will propel. In the case of a 3-phase induction motor, the starting torque exhibits a direct proportionality to the square of the initial current. Several methods, such as the Full Load Current (FLC) and the Locked Rotor Current (LRC) of the motor, can be employed to estimate the starting current. The determination of starting torque and current typically hinges on factors like the type of load and the desired acceleration. It's worth noting that for a basic illustration, I can outline a general procedure for computing rotor resistance and its associated resistors. However, for precise calculations, consulting a professional electrical engineer and referring to the motor manufacturer's documentation is recommended.

Let's assume you want to calculate the rotor resistance starter for a moderate starting torque, using the Full Load Current method. Here's how you can proceed:

First, you'll need to find the FLC, which is given by:

$$\displaystyle\text{I}_\text{FLC}=\frac{\displaystyle\text{P}_\text{m}}{\displaystyle\eta\text{V}_\text{m}\cos\left(\varphi\right)\sqrt{3}}\tag1$$

Where \$\displaystyle\text{I}_\text{FLC}\space\left[\text{A}\right]\$ is the full load current, \$\displaystyle\text{P}_\text{m}\space\left[\text{W}\right]\$ (notice that \$1\space\text{hp}_\text{electrical}=746\space\text{W}\$) is the power of the motor, \$\displaystyle\text{V}_\text{m}\space\left[\text{V}\right]\$ is the voltage, \$\displaystyle\cos\left(\varphi\right)\space\left[-\right]\$ is the power factor and \$\displaystyle\eta\space\left[-\right]\$ is the efficiency of the motor.

Now, we must find the starting current \$\displaystyle\text{I}_\text{start}\space\left[\text{A}\right]\$. The starting current can be estimated as a factor of the full load current, typically ranging from 5 to 8 times the FLC, depending on the type of load. So, we can write:

$$\displaystyle\text{I}_\text{start}=\text{n}\text{I}_\text{FLC}\tag2$$

Now, we must find the rotor resistance. The starting torque \$\displaystyle\tau_\text{start}\space\left[\text{Nm}\right]\$ is proportional to the square of the starting current. The torque equation for an induction motor is:

$$\displaystyle\tau_\text{start}=\text{k}\text{I}_\text{start}^2\tag3$$

\$\displaystyle\text{k}\$ is a constant that depends on the motor design and is usually provided by the manufacturer.

The starting torque is also related to the rotor resistance \$\displaystyle\text{R}_\text{rotor}\space\left[\Omega\right]\$ by the equation:

$$\displaystyle\tau_\text{start}=\frac{\displaystyle3\text{V}_\text{m}^2}{2\pi\text{f}_\text{s}\text{R}_\text{rotor}}\tag4$$

Where \$\displaystyle\text{f}_\text{s}\space\left[\text{Hz}\right]\$ is the slip frequency and that is given by:

$$\displaystyle\text{f}_\text{s}=\frac{\displaystyle\text{p}_\text{#}}{\displaystyle120}\cdot\left|\frac{\displaystyle120\text{f}_\text{source}}{\displaystyle\text{p}_\text{#}}-\text{n}_\text{m}\right|\tag5$$

Where \$\displaystyle\text{p}_\text{#}\space\left[-\right]\$ is the amount of poles, \$\displaystyle\text{f}_\text{source}\space\left[\text{Hz}\right]\$ is the input frequency of the source and \$\displaystyle\text{n}_\text{m}\space\left[\text{rpm}\right]\$ is the actual speed of the motor.

So, when combining we can see that:

$$\displaystyle\text{k}\left(\text{n}\cdot\frac{\displaystyle\text{P}_\text{m}}{\displaystyle\eta\text{V}_\text{m}\cos\left(\varphi\right)\sqrt{3}}\right)^2=\frac{\displaystyle3\text{V}_\text{m}^2}{2\pi\cdot\frac{\displaystyle\text{p}_\text{#}}{\displaystyle120}\cdot\left|\frac{\displaystyle120\text{f}_\text{source}}{\displaystyle\text{p}_\text{#}}-\text{n}_\text{m}\right|\cdot\text{R}_\text{rotor}}\tag6$$

Using your values, and assuming that \$\displaystyle\text{k}=\frac{1}{100}\$, \$\displaystyle\text{n}=5\$ and \$\displaystyle\eta=\cos\left(\varphi\right)=\frac{17}{20}\$,  we get:

$$\displaystyle\frac{1}{100}\left(5\cdot\frac{\displaystyle373}{\displaystyle\frac{17}{20}\cdot400\cdot\frac{17}{20}\cdot\sqrt{3}}\right)^2=\frac{\displaystyle3\cdot400^2}{2\pi\cdot\frac{\displaystyle4}{\displaystyle120}\cdot\left|\frac{\displaystyle120\cdot50}{\displaystyle4}-1750\right|\cdot\text{R}_\text{rotor}}\tag7$$

Which gives:

$$\displaystyle\text{R}_\text{rotor}=\frac{\displaystyle28864857600}{\displaystyle139129\pi}\approx66039.2\space\Omega\tag8$$

Comment: thank you very much  , could you also please let me know the ratings for this resistor?